# Search for colors

Tags: linux, notepad++, css

I'm looking for a way to find all CSS colors (HEX) in a directory recursively, I don't know the colors i'll be looking for so I want a way using notepad++ or any linux command to find strings that start with a "#" and then followed by 6 characters just like the CSS hex codes i.e: #111111

Comment: Answered on SO, see [php - Regex for matching CSS hex colors - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837942/regex-for-matching-css-hex-colors)

Comment: [Match or Validate CCS colors - Regex Tester/Debugger](https://www.regextester.com/103656)

Comment: [RegExr: CSS colors](https://regexr.com/38lmo)

Comment: [CSS Hex color validator - Regex Tester/Debugger](https://www.regextester.com/93840)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone wants this, you can use this regex:

```
#([a-fA-F0-9]{6})
```

Comment: Warning: the ranges may match more than you think. Compare [Why does `[A-Z]` match lowercase letters in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/227070/108618) That question is about Bash but the issue is general.

Comment: Yes you are right, I actually faced that, but in general it solved my problem.

Comment: Be aware that your regex matches `#123456` in the string `blah#123456XYZ`